# Single Standard for multiple Idp Claim Types

Tags: single-sign-on

I want my application to use different Identity Providers for SSO. With claims returned by it I want to use only couple of them for a description of the user in my application. The problem is I do not want to map claim types for every single Idp used in my configuration, so seeking for a solution where every Idp returns common set of claim types. Are there any common standards for claim types definied for Idps?

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by having our own Identity provider.  This one worked with our own user store.  It also worked with other identity providers (Facebook, Twitter ...).  One of the main task it has was to consolidate the claims returned to the relying parties.  This way the relying parties only had to know one IP and the IP made sure that the claims returned where consistent regardless of the underlying IP that was used (we did provide some stuff like initialauthenticationmethod to *allow* RP's to distinguish if they really wanted.